# combobox filter in c# based onother value

Tags: c#, combobox

I have 2 comboboxes .`txtlocation` ,`txtstep`

I added these item statically.The items of `txtlocation` are :`TO
QC
TP
MAT
SUP
DCC
FIN
REC
SIG`

And the `txtstep` items are :

```
TO As SUP
TO As PIP
TO  HW
TO  MOD
TO  FSQ
QC HW
QC LC
QC RE
QC TEST
QC PAD
QC WJCS
TP 
MAT NIS
MAT DATA
SUP ASBUILT
SUP REPORT
SUP REPORT/ASBUILT
DCC MONO LC
DCC MONO RE
FIN LC
FIN PAD
FIN TEST
FIN DRY
FIN FL
FIN RE
REC FIN LC
REC FIN  PAD
REC FIN TEST
REC FIN DRY
REC FIN FL
REC FIN RE
SIG LC
SIG PAD
SIG TEST
SIG DRY
SIG FL
SIG RE
```

I add an event(selectedindexchang) on `txtlocation`.if the user select `TO`
the step of TO should be filtered.`TO As SUP
    TO As PIP
    TO  HW
    TO  MOD
    TO  FSQ`

Should i use datasource ?

```
 private void txtlocation_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
```

Comment: You can use `DataSet`. Or you can simply create array of names and filter them.

Comment: @Prajwal can i filter directly the item list of combobox?

Comment: Yea. Or you can add items once the other combobox value is set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different DataSources will be maybe clearer way, you can use `Dictionary<TLocation, List<TStep>>` for linking selected value with correspondent datasource.

```
private Dictionary<string, List<string>> _data = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    { "TO", new List<string> { "TO AS SUP", "TO AS PIP" }},
    { "DCC", new List<string> { "DCC MONO LC", "DCC MONO RE" }},
    { "MAT", new List<string> { "MAT NIS", "MAT DATA" }},
};

comboBoxLocation.DataSource = data.Keys.ToList();
```

The use `SelectedValueChanged` eventhandler for setting correct datasource beased on the location selection.

```
private void comboBoxlocation_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboBoxLocations = (ComboBox)sender;
    comboBoxSteps.DataSource = _data[comboBoxLocations.SelectedValue.ToString()];
}
```

If you have only one list of steps you can filter the list and set filtered result as DataSource.

```
private void comboBoxlocation_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var comboBoxLocations = (ComboBox)sender;
    var selectedLocation = comboBoxLocations.SelectedValue.ToString();
    comboBoxSteps.DataSource = _AllSteps.Where(step => step.StartsWith(selectedLocation))
                                        .ToList();
}
```

With this approach you will loop the list every time you made change in the location combobox.